# How do I use docker containers to read, sort and join text files?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I'm new to Linux and Docker, and I'm currently working on some university assignments. I've been trying my best to understand this assignment - but I really cannot. My assignment needs me to create a script which will compile various text files into one big text file. The idea is to use docker to load text files into three different docker containers, at which point I have to use round-robin scheduling to sort and rearrange the files. Once sorted, these text files need to be compiled into one big text file.

To help with this assignment, I've been trying to get a better understanding of what Docker is and what its purpose is. As far as I can tell, it appears to be a sort of mini-VM for specific things (ubuntu, nginx, mysql, etc), but I don't really see how this pertains to my task. I imagine I've to create ubuntu dockers and load files into them, but how am I supposed to do that? Every time I try to look into how I could attempt that, I'm greeted with copious amounts of commands that I can hardly read, let alone understand.

I've created a simple script that throws up a CLI as a starting point, but I genuinely don't know where to go from here. I'm honestly at a complete loss here, we've covered docker very briefly, and it was never insinuated that docker will play such a major role in my grade.

I know this is a bit of a messy post, and I'm sure what I've written regarding Docker is probably wrong - but I would appreciate any kind of advice or help. Linux is a tough nut to crack..

Comment: Certainly reading the task description, Docker isn't the first tool that comes to mind: since each container has an isolated filesystem, it's distinctly harder to use it around file-centric workflows.  I might think through how you'd build this application otherwise (is it one script, or several? if several, how do they communicate?  is a message queue involved?), actually build it without Docker, and then figure out how to package it in Docker images and run it in containers.